# Next.js - Using more than one global style in a component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, styled-jsx

In my Next.js project, I have a component which is importing only one CSS file like this:

```
import stylesheet from '../src/styles/first.scss';
```

And it's used like this:

```
return (
  <Layout>
    <style global jsx>{stylesheet}</style>
    more code goes here
  </layout>
```

Now I need to import a second CSS file in my component like this:

```
import secondStylesheet from '../src/styles/second.scss';
```

But how can I use the second CSS?
I tried the followings but it didn't work:

```
return (
  <Layout>
    <style global jsx>{stylesheet, secondStylesheet}</style>
    more code goes here
  </layout>
```

AND:

```
return (
  <Layout>
    <style global jsx>{stylesheet}</style>
    <style global jsx>{secondStylesheet}</style>
    more code goes here
  </layout>
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Can you r using  instead of  and try putting code before your style jsx's

```
    return (
  <Layout>
    more code goes here
    <style global jsx>{stylesheet}</style>
    <style global jsx>{secondStylesheet}</style>
  </Layout>
   )
```